# python: write a http proxy for a remote proxy?

Tags: python, proxy

so here's the situation. I have a proxy but needs to pass authorization headers. I want a proxy that only I can access from my server without having to write the headers.

how can I do this in python? basically all I'm doing is adding authorization headers to another remote proxy.

```
me -> server -> python server (passes auth headers) -> remote proxy
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try connectiong to proxy through this piece of code

```
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":"http://...."})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```